# How to create a dataframe that only includes rows where a condition is satisfied?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My prompt is to "Create a dataframe of the locations, states, and differences for all locations where females drink more than males" I am supposed to use dplyr and I know I should probably filter but I am not sure how to piece it all together. My end goal is to have another column called "female_difference" where the difference will be displayed if the data for the women is larger than for the men. If the data for the men is larger, I want to display a 0. Let me know if any more clarification is needed. Thank you!

Format of the data I'm working with:

| State | Location | females_2012 | males_2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WA | County | 22.1 | 33.2 |

Comment: Are you using online dataset ? If you're share a link with me. I will do it for you. and share code here

Comment: `datasetname %>% mutate(female_difference = ifelse(females_2012 > males_2012, females_2012 - males_2012, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using mutate, we can achieve this.
Please install 'tidyverse' library and load it first.

```
   library(tidyverse)
    datasetname %>% mutate(female_difference = females_2012 > males_2012)
```

Comment: It will return TRUE or FALSE. Hope you will get it now